# how to allow TCP response packets enter network and how to configure it in access-list?

Tags: tcp, router

What is TCP response packets?
How to meet this requirement in access-list on a router?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look up stateful firewalling for whatever router you're using.

TCP response packets are basically any related TCP packets that come back after an initial SYN has been sent. Typically this would be either a packet with SYN+ACK set, or one with RST if the connection was refused.

Stateful firewalls keep track of not just the source and destination of individual packets, but what connection the packets belong to. By doing this they are able to distinguish between expected, legitimate replies to SYN packets (and others) and random or malicious unrequested "replies".